# Is high CPU temperature directly related to a Blue Screen?

Tags: cpu

First of all I'd like to note that this is not about solving my issue at hand per se, the PC in question will be brought to someone to fix it, it is more a question out of curiousity.

So here is the thing, the PC has an i7-920 CPU. It has been working fine for the past years.
However since a few days the CPU fan is not spinning anymore (suspecting it is broken), but at the same time I'm getting bluescreens when the CPU temperature reaches above 85 degrees celsius.

I am wondering if there is a **direct** relation to the CPU temperature and Windows blue screening? All I know is that my BIOS is not controlling this, the i7-920 shuts itself down at 105 degrees celsius. So why exactly am I getting a Blue Screen?

Any explanation would be highly appreciated, just out of curiousity.

ps. Something that does concern me. Several years ago I have ran Prime95 for hours on this PC and the temperature would be at a steady 95C, with the fan running obviously. Yet now on 85C it is already blue screening.

Comment: No direct connection, probably crash related to drivers, but I'm not sure about this one. By the way, try cleaning dust from the CPU fan, it may be blocking the blades.

Comment: @matan129 Already tried that, sadly didn't help. Though the fan decides to sometimes spin, like 1 minute out of 60 minutes total, completely random. I don't exactly know what is going on.

Comment: Well, then as you said, it may be just broken. Try to check the on-board power plug of the fan, maybe it moved (rare, but possible). @techie007: he's PC isn't freezing, but rather it's BSoD. And he also asked for **connection**.

Comment: Freezing and BSoD are very similar, especially when in context to "Can CPU overheat heat cause the computer to crash?".  The other question covers it, as well as some tips on how to avoid it.  also, this question as-is is kind of vague and hypothetical, two things that aren't generally accepted on SU (if we can help it).

Comment: The odds are, there is no direct correlation between the CPU and the BSoD in this OPs case, it's probably some other device crapping out due to the CPU overheat.  The STOP code may lead the OP to that device.  The _cause_ is the cooling system being busted.  So the question could perhaps be reworded to "What's the direct connection between a busted fan and getting a BSoD?"  :)

Comment: The question is why is your CPU so hot in the first place?  If my CPU was running that hot I would buy a bigger better heatsink.  Something with a copper based and copper heat pipes and aluminum fins.

Comment: It's quite possible that the lack of airflow and the additional heat now being radiated by the CPU are allowing some other component (such as your RAM) to overheat, leading to the blue screens.

Comment: someone needs new thermal paste a new heatsink. as suggested by @cybernard

Answer (score 0):

There are 100's of reasons for a blue screen.  Your CPU overheating is just one of them.  If the heat causes the CPU to generate errors these errors can cause a Blue Screen (BSOD).